# Translating English into Predicate Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Which of the following are possible (semantically and syntactically correct) first-order-logic translation of "Salma loves any class which is harder than every Algorithms class".

Is the following translation correct ? and Why ?

$\forall x \forall y[[Class(x) \land AlClass(y) \land Harder(x,y)] \to Loves(Salma,x)]$

My prof considered it as a wrong translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would actually end up meaning "Salma loves any class which is harder than some Algorithms class."

To see why, consider taking any $x$ and $y$ where $x$ is a class, $y$ is an algorithms class, and $x$ is harder than $y,$ and see that this implies that Salma loves $x,$ regardless of whether $x$ is harder than any other algorithms class.

I believe a correct translation would be $\forall x \Big[\big[\text{Class}(x) \wedge [\forall y \text{AlClass}(y) \to \text{Harder}(x,y)]\big] \to \text{Loves}(\text{Salma}, x)\Big].$

---

Edit: here's a more concrete counterexample for why the two translations are not the same.

Let's say we had three classes, $a, b_1, b_2,$ where $b_1$ and $b_2$ are algorithms classes and $a$ is harder than $b_1,$ but not $b_2.$

Using your translation, because the sentence must hold for all $x$ and $y,$ it must hold when we use the substution $x = a, y = b_1,$ so $[\text{Class}(a) \wedge \text{AlClass}(b_1) \wedge \text{Harder}(a, b_1)] \to \text{Loves}(\text{Salma}, a).$

Now from our definitions we know that $\text{Class}(a), \text{AlClass}(b_1),$ and $\text{Harder}(a, b_1)$ are all true, so by conjunction we get $\text{Class}(a) \wedge \text{AlClass}(b_1) \wedge \text{Harder}(a, b_1),$ and by Modus Ponens we get $\text{Loves}(\text{Salma}, a).$ So, Salma must love $a,$ regardless of whether $a$ is harder than $b_2,$ or any other algorithms class.

But if you look at my translation, letting $x = a,$ it is not true that $\forall y [\text{AlClass}(y) \to \text{Harder}(a, y)]$ because this is not true for $b_2,$ which both is an algorithms class and is not strictly less hard than $a.$ This doesn't proclude Salma from loving $a,$ but this translation does not imply that Salma must love $a.$

Comment: i think that what you wrote is for sure correct and make sense and i think what i wrote fulfil the purpose but does not make sense like your trans, my argument was that we have to loop over all algorithms classes till the end of the domain  and then if there is any assignment that makes the implication false the overall expression will be false. in other words i think there is no case the overall expression of you and me will throw different final results as truth values

Comment: i have used the fact says that universal quantifiers may be represented by a chain of conjunctions , so imagine that there is an assignment that makes the antecedent true and the consequent false ,therefore all that terms in that chain of conjunctions will throw false

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something, I'm going to edit to include a more concrete counterexample.

Comment: i got it. Thank you so much.